# How to best support a dual interface CPU vs GPU?

Tags: c++, cuda, eigen

I have a project developed using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) that implements multiple HPC methods e.g. optimization and that was initially targeting the CPU. As the code grows I have the CPU-only Eigen types MatrixXd and VectorXd everywhere as part of my public interfaces e.g.

```
/// Base abstract definition for a System Solver strategy.
/**
 * Base abstract definition for a System Solver strategy.
 */
class SolverInterface {
private:
    DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN(SolverInterface);

public:
    /// Default constructor
    /**
     * Default empty constructor
     */
    SolverInterface() { /* empty */ }

    /// Solves the given system either determined or over-determined.
    /**
     * Solves the given system either determined or over-determined and returns
     * the solution.
     *
     * \param A squared or overdetermined matrix
     * \param b vector of responses
     */
    virtual const VectorXd& solve(const MatrixXd& A, const VectorXd& b) = 0;

    /// Destructor
    /**
     * Destructor
     */
    virtual ~SolverInterface() { /* empty */ }
};
```

At this point I'd like to also have native GPU implementations for many of the algorithms and therefore the abstract interfaces need to be changed in some way. However, it is not extremely clear what the best design strategy would be, this is a summary of the possibilities:

1. Overloading: overload the different interfaces with an additional method that would support the GPU implementations e.g. `virtual double* solve(double* d_A, int m, int n, double* d_b) = 0;`.

   - Pros: simple solution, at the client side the code looks somewhat cleaner
   - Cons: inelegant, promotes the if-then-else ladder antipatten if-CPU-call-CPU-else-call-GPU.
2. Template: Change the `SolverInterface` to be a template class taking as template parameters the Matrix and Vector types.

   - Pros: The solver hierarchy and concrete implementations will be clean and succinct.
   - Cons: Covariant assignment of template classes does not work. I don't know how to overcome the type covariance limitation elegantly, it is also true that each will require different inputs to work. This choice feels like the template escalates all the way up to the client and leads to a more end user code complexity.
3. DeviceMatrixXd: that extends MatrixXd (my favourite alternative), the device alternative would have e.g. an additional attribute double* d_data containing the device memory and methods like e.g. `updateHost()` and `updateDevice()` to sync back and forth:

   - Pros: big plus that Interfaces don't need changing.
   - Cons: Creating a DeviceMatrixXd subclass of MatrixXd breaks the expression template design principle in Eigen. It also incurs in double storage that may not always be necessary e.g. when using or passing a matrix that doesn't need conversion to Host memory.

Any other suggestions, maybe some clever design using traits?

For the possibility #2 one would end with the following covariant assignment issue:

```
  // this will not compile!
  SolverInterface<?,?>* solver = NULL;
  if (CPU) {
      // extends SolverInterface<MatrixXd,VectorXd>
      solver = new CPULeastSquaresSolver(); 
  } else {
      // extends SolverInterface<double*,double*>
      solver = new GPULeastSquaresSolver();
  }
```

Comment: This is a very broad question which has attracted no responses in the two years since it was posted and I've voted to close it as such.